# Meteor Publish and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to decide or find out which option is the best practices when it comes to Meteor publish and MongoDB.

I have an organization that will have over 300 users, my first option is just adding a userId array to the organization mongo document and doing the following:

```
Meteor.publish('organizationsUsers', function() {
    var organization = Organizations.findOne({_id: this.userId});.fetch();
    var usersArray = _.flatten(_.pluck(organization, "users"), true);
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: {$in: usersArray}}); 
});
```

My second option is just adding an organizationId to each user and doing the following:

```
Meteor.publish('organizationsUsers', function() {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
     return Meteor.users.find({organizationId: user.organizationId});
});
```

With the first option I have MongoDB with a long array and with the second option its simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Ok some after some quick research and asking around general rule if your field is more the 100 items which in my case would be over 300 it's better to go with the second approach.

Also when mongo queries all the users belonging to an organization with the first option mongo takes the entire array and looks each via the index, with the second option just via the index.

Comment: Just make sure that you have an index on organizationID and the second one should always be faster.