# Meteor users find not returning in publish

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to return meteor user with a org ID but I'm not getting anything back.

```
Meteor.publish('organizationsUsers', function() {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
    return Meteor.users.find({organizationId: user.organizationId});
});
```

My router

```
Meteor.subscribe('organizationsUsers');
```

And the view

```
organizationsUsers: function() {
        if (!this.users)
            return;
        return Meteor.users.find(); // {}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}
    }
```

In my template I have

```
{{#each organizationsUsers}}
{{> userItem}}
{{/each}}
```

And in the JS

```
organizationsUsers: function() {
        if (!this.users)
            return;
        return Meteor.users.find(); // {}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}
    },
```

Comment: `Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});` you have to pass a key in mongo search

Comment: No it's already returning the correct id with it or without the key this is not working = Meteor.users.find({organizationId: user.organizationId});

Comment: Can you verify that on your server your query has results? Such as debugging through your publish and running the query in the debugger or doing a console log of the results length?

Comment: Also @Rajanand02 You're correct that the key missing would be a problem in Mongo but Meteor has a trick in the background that a single string parameter will query on the _id.

Comment: Did a console log
console.log(user.organizationId);
return the id 

console.log(Meteor.users.find({organizationId:  console.log(Meteor.users.find({organizationId: user.organizationId}).length);
console.log(Meteor.users.find().length);
getting undefined

Comment: `console.log(Meteor.users.find({organizationId: console.log(Meteor.users.find({organizationId: user.organizationId}).length);` wut? do `console.log(Meteor.users.find({organizationId : user.organizationId}).fetch().length);` and see if that gets you a number greater than 0.

Comment: Yea did it fast right before heading out of the office well test again as soon as i get home thanks

Comment: I'm getting 2 for both 
console.log(Meteor.users.find({organizationId : user.organizationId}).fetch().length);
    console.log(Meteor.users.find().fetch().length);

Comment: Wow I think I figured out the Meteor was not publishing orgId

Answer (score 0):

You should not do multiple queries or joins in the publish function if you want to return a cursor, instead do something like this:

```
// CLIENT
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  if (Meteor.userId()) {
    if (typeof organizationId === 'string') {
      Meteor.subscribe('organizationsUsers', Meteor.user().organizationId);
    } else {
      console.log('error');
      // if necessary, debug why organizationId is not a string
    }
  }
});

// SERVER
Meteor.publish('organizationsUsers', function(organizationId) {
  check(organizationId, String);
  return Meteor.users.find({organizationId: organizationId});
});
```

Comment: Is there a reasoning behind this? It doesn't seem like this would fix the problem he's seeing.

Comment: I don't think this is correct "should not do multiple queries or joins in the publish function" Meteor docs has example with multiple queries and I have seen it in a number of examples.

Comment: @mikael this has an error - Exception from sub mduZBmZpxC9axFD4m Error: Match error: Expected string, got object

Comment: @AlmogKoren organizationId is probably null (object), which sometimes happens if the Meteor.user() has not populated yet. I've updated my example so to avoid that.

Comment: @MikaelLirbank yea I ended up doing that, but I'm using Iron-router shouldn't have to do this check and this is still not the main issue. The main issue is with showing the data in the template

Comment: @Shaded - if you run multiple queries (ie. joins) in a publish function it will not update reactively. But if use Meteor.user() on the client it's a reactive data source, and if you run it in Tracker.autorun() which is runs code as a reactive computation it will re-subscribe each time Meteor.user() changes, and thus the publish() will rerun.

Comment: @MikaelLirbank got it working it was an issue with the template code. I do think your approach is a bit nicer however I would wonder if there are any security risk passing the org.Id to the publish via the client or even using iron-router which runs both on the client and sever, wouldn't it be possible for a user to pass in random Ids and get private data?

Comment: @MikaelLirbank I'm also not sure on the hole if statements doesn't feel elegant. But if there was a good example using iron-router that might work. I might give it another try. How would you do it using iron-router?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, first I was using the same code that I had for a publish function which was using  a userId array in the org ([Meteor Publish and MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27299592/meteor-publish-and-mongodb/27299732)). mongo doc. And for the template I had the following:

```
organizationsUsers: function() {
    if (!this.users)
         return;
          return Meteor.users.find(); // {}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}
}
```

The if statement was casing the issue, this work

```
 organizationsUsers: function() {
    return Meteor.users.find(); // {}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}
```

}